# How to view the contents of a vector of tuples when debugging in LLDB?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, rust, lldb, codelldb

I'm using Visual Studio Code and the LLDB Debugger (CodeLLDB vadimcn.vscode-lldb) for programming in Rust. When using `Vec<u64>` I can see all values in a list (until a limit of > 10000):

[image: All entries of Vec]

When using a vector of tuples (`Vec<(u64, u64)>`), I can't see inside the vector.

[image]

When digging a bit deeper, I only find a pointer which points to the first entry in the vector. I'm not able to get to another position in my vector.

How do I get the content of the whole vector? Maybe with some watch expression?

I'm using Rust 1.44.1

Comment: I'm also seeing this using v1.5.3 of CodeLLDB. I've added `"sourceLanguages": ["rust"]` to my launch.json but I'm still unable to view the tuples. I also noticed that if I have

`let mut some_vec: Vec<(u64, u64)> = Vec::new();`
`some_vec.push((64, 64));`
`some_vec.push((63, 63));`

and then in the debugger console I run

`p some_vec[0]`

I get a `Index '0' is out of range` error, which is clearly wrong. So this makes me think it's a bug in CodeLLDB and not knowing how to interpret Vecs of tuples in Rust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been addressed in the latest version of `CodeLLDB v1.7.0`

rust : `1.60.0 (7737e0b5c 2022-04-04)`
vscode: `v1.67.0`\

Code used

```
use std::vec;

fn main() {
    let my_vec_of_tuples: Vec<(u64, u64)> = vec![(1, 2), (3, 4)];
    println!("you guessed : {:?}", my_vec_of_tuples);
}
```

code lldb debug view

```
my_vec_of_tuples: (2) vec![(1, 2), (3, 4)]
my_vec_of_tuples[0]: (1, 2)
```

Know it's not recommended to post images as part of answers but it's more appropriate here and required to answer the image.

[image]